# cursor.fetchone() returns None but row in the database exists

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am writing a program on python which interacts with MySQL database.
For sql queries I use MySQLdb. 
The problem is that `fetchone()` returns None but with the database browser I can see that **that** row exists. 
This piece of code:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM revision WHERE rev_id=%s;" 
cursor.execute(query % revision_id)
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row == None:
    raise Exception("there isn't revision with id %s" % revision_id)
```

I have no idea what is going on here. Any ideas?

EDIT: okay, in some cases it works in some cases it doesn't but anyway when it
does not work the row exists in the table. I am passing a cursor object to a function and the code above is in the function. The problem is connected with this cursor object. Could the problem be that I pass the cursor as an argument to the function? How can I test it?

EDIT2: yes, the problem is that cursor does not work after I use it several times. Wether because other program connects to the DB or I am doing something wrong.
I have `while` loop in which I call a function to get info from the DB. After some iterations it does not work again. There is another program which writes to 
the DB while `while` loop works.

Comment: `print` the query string (with its substitution) to the screen and copy/paste it into a `mysql` prompt to be certain.

Comment: Better yet, use a parametrized query instead of substituting.

Comment: yes, the query string works fine in mysql promt

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams could you give an example?

Comment: A parametrized query has place holders (usually a ?, but it doesn't have to be, it's per implementation) for values that you also pass alongside the string when executing some SQL.  This prevents SQL injection because the database API is able to do this safely, where using `'%s' % value` does not do the substitution safely and is prone to SQL injection.  This doesn't have much do do with your original question though.

Comment: Some idea: 1) loose the ";" at the end of the sql statement 2) check how you connect to the database. If it is ODBC/DSN, you might want to double check if the DSN is pointing to the right database server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, `db.autocommit(True)` solved my problem.

Comment: `connection.commit()` after your `execute` (or `db.commit()`, depending on what you called your connection) can do the same thing, manually.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to transaction isolation level on your MySQL server. In the case of `REPEATABLE_READ` which is the default level for InnoDb, a snapshot is created at the time of first read, and subsequent read by the same cursor are made from this snapshot. Read more about isolation levels [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)

What we usually require while reusing the same cursor to run multiple queries, is `READ_COMMITTED`. Thankfully, if you can not change this on your SQL server, you can set your cursor to a particular isolation level.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED")
```

This makes sure that every query you make, there is a fresh latest committed snapshot is used.

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice is to commit db, after all query executed   `db.commit()`