# None is returned when using cursor.fetchone() to select count()

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I wrote a sql like this:

```
"select count(md5) from table_file_log where md5=\'%s\'" % my_md5
```

`my_md5` is a string passed to the method.
When I used `fetchone()` I got `None` returned.

Actually I usually prefer `fetchall()` to avoid `None` returned, but I believe `count()` should get `(0,)` instead of `None`, even if there is no record.
I added logging to print the sql and pasted it in mysql and correct count was returned.

One more thing, in my program, hundreds of the same kind of sql got executed, and some of them got `None`, some of them got correct results like `(0,)` or `(1,)`.

I tried to search solutions on this site, the only post I found that seemed related to my question is this:
[cursor.fetchone() returns None but row in the database exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821976/cursor-fetchone-returns-none-but-row-in-the-database-exists)
But I don't understand why autocommit would work in that question. Even if that's the answer I would like to know the reason.

I use Python 2.7 and mysql-connector, and MyISAM as the engine.

Comment: md5 is a method in mysql. I think you better put the quote for it if it's a field in a table.

Comment: @haudoing could be the reason. But why I got correct result sometimes, and I always got correct answers for the same sql in command line?

Comment: My assumption is that there might be a bug in that lib or connection error. But we can only know that by tracing the code. Try directly query in mysql to see what happen too. Or maybe change to other mysql driver. I used to use [MySQLdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4) as the driver for django.

Comment: Here is the list of mysql driver which django recommend https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

Comment: Does `count(*)` make a difference? Just a wild guess because I'm used to doing it that way.

Comment: @haudoing it's not very possible to  change the driver for this project now..thanks though

Comment: @StefanPochmann Right, I just realized that I'm actually used to writing `count(*)` too， maybe I should try this.